# How do I construct an if else statement to check if a combobox value is within a certain range

Tags: excel, if-statement, combobox, vba

I have a combobox list that is comprised of 5 ranges each from a different worksheet from a different workbook.  I want to check if the combobox value is within a certain range (check to see what worksheet its in) by using an if else statement, but I can't get the code to work:

```
Sub TextBox2_Change()

Dim value As String
    value = ComboBox1.value

Dim bdate As String
    bdate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
Dim ddate As Date

Dim Found As range
Set Found = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx") _
            .Worksheets("Sheet1",  "Sheet2", "Sheet3") _                                  
            .Columns("A").Find(what:=value, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Found = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1") _
           .Columns("A").Find(what:=value, LookIn:=xlValues) Then
    ddate = DateAdd("m", 2, bdate)
ElseIf Found = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2") _ 
               .Columns("A").Find(what:=value, LookIn:=xlValues) Then
    ddate = DateAdd("h", 3, bdate)
ElseIf Found = Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet3") _    
               .Columns("A").Find(what:=value, LookIn:=xlValues) Then
    ddate = DateAdd("d", 2, bdate)
End If

Msgbox "" &ddate, vbinformation

End Sub
```

**PLEASE HELP!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

`Range.Find` will not work on multiple worksheets.

This syntax is misleading because Date values are numbers:

`bdate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")`

It is good practice to use the `DateValue` function instead:

bdate = DateValue(Now())

```
Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Found As Range
    Dim bdate As String
    Dim value As String
    value = ComboBox1.value
    bdate = DateValue(Now())
    Dim ddate As Date
    For Each ws In Workbooks("Library_Database.xlsx").Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
        Set Found = ws.Columns("A").Find(what:=value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet3"
                ddate = DateAdd("m", 2, bdate)
            Case "Sheet2"
                ddate = DateAdd("h", 3, bdate)
            End Select
            MsgBox "Date: " & ddate, vbInformation, "Date Found"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Found Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Try Again", vbCritical, "Date Not Found"

End Sub
```